# Not able to cast in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my date which looks something like this.

[image: data]

I want to get sum of `ITEM_QTY` which has `varchar` datatype currently and tried following ways after typecasting but none of them worked.

1. ```sql
   SELECT SUM(TRY_CAST(ITEM_QTY as bigint))
   FROM sales219
   ```

   Result:

   > [image: output]
2. ```sql
   SELECT SUM(CAST(ITEM_QTY as bigint))
   FROM sales219
   ```

   Output:

   > Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
3. ```sql
   SELECT SUM(convert(bigint,ITEM_QTY))
   FROM sales219
   ```

   Output:

   > Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
4. ```sql
   SELECT SUM(try_convert(bigint,ITEM_QTY))
   FROM sales219
   ```

   Output:

   > [image: output]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your post with sample data in a textual form rather than links/images. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) are the reasons why using them is very low quality.

Comment: What's with all the quotes around your data?

Comment: You will want to remove the double quotes from your data.   In the mean time try this:  Select sum(try_convert(bigint,replace([ITEM_QTY],'"',''))) from YourTable

Comment: Or rather, fix your importing process to stop putting the quotes there to begin with. Are you populating the table from a CSV?

Comment: Fix the data as well as the column definitions. The columns should have been defined in the correct data types and imported properly in the first place

Comment: First, execute UPDATE Date = REPLACE(Date, '"', '') ...

Comment: FROM SRCTABLE and then SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to remove the double quotes from your data. In the mean time try this:

```
Select sum(try_convert(bigint,replace([ITEM_QTY],'"',''))) from YourTable
```

Or rather, fix your importing process to stop putting the quotes there to begin with.